# Model does not update within ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I've got a strange behavior in an angular application and I don't know if that's a bug or a known limitation:

```js
'use strict';

var ctrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
  foo: {{foo}}
  <div ng-if="foo" style="background-color: #f00;">
    <p>foo</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!foo">
    <br/><button ng-click="foo = true;">Show foo</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="foo = true">Show foo</button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/78R52/

I would expect that clicking one of the buttons would set `foo = true`, but clicking the first button (within the `ng-if="!foo"`) doesn't change the model.

Tested version is `1.2.1`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ng-if` has its own scope, so you need to use:

```
<br/><button ng-click="$parent.foo = true;">Show foo</button>
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/78R52/1/

Comment: Thank you. I had this idea right after posting my question, too. Should have been looking into the docs of `ng-if` before asking...

Comment: Thanks! Found this before pulling my hair off!

Answer (score 5):

Ah, `ng-if` creates a new scope! So, "there has to be a dot in the model name"!

http://jsfiddle.net/78R52/2/

Comment: Right, and since the ng-if scope is a child of the controller scope, you could also use $parent.foo to access foo on the controller scope.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, ng-if has its own scope.
What i want to say, it's a bad practice to put expressions in the view. The good practice is to have a scope function that's called within the view.

```
var ctrl = function($scope){
$scope.foo = false;
$scope.fn = fn;
function fn(){
$scope.foo = true;
}
/////

<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl">
  foo: {{foo}}
  <div ng-if="foo" style="background-color: #f00;">
    <p>foo</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!foo">
    <br/><button ng-click="fn()">Show foo</button>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="fn()">Show foo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Any arguments, why you call this a bad practice?

Comment: You know, angular has lots of good and bad practices. I've called it a bad practice since problems like yours may appear, especially when having multiple scopes encapsulating each other, like multiple ng-repeats, ng-ifs and other directives.