# Strage behavior of ng-class when ng-if is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-scope

I have this piece of code:

```
....
<article class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul ng-if="isLogged()" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{'active': activeUrl === 'projects'}">
            <a href="#/projects" ng-click="activeUrl='projects'">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="isAdmin()" ng-class="{'active': activeUrl === 'admin'}">
            <a href="#/admin" ng-click="activeUrl='admin'">Administration</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

And it should add `active` class when link is clicked. It worked very well until I added `ng-if` expressions, which mock user authentication. Now when it adds `active` class once, it doesn't remove this class when another navigation link is clicked - it looks like 2 pages are opened in the same time. 
There is `applicationController` which has mock functions:

```
applicationController= function($scope, Restangular, userService){
    $scope.activeUrl = "admin";
    $scope.data = {
        user: {
        email: undefined,
        password: undefined
        }
    };

    $scope.login = function(user){
        //login mock
    };

    $scope.isLogged = function(){
        return userService.isLogged();
    };

     $scope.isAdmin = function(){
        return userService.isAdmin();
    };
};
```

And `userService` has logic which determine if user is authenticated and if is administrator. I don't think that `ng-if` with `ng-class` in one HTML element is something unusual, that's why I think I must made some simple mistake which I can't see. Is scope recreated after any click? I would be very happy if anybody helps me - thank you in advance! 
**Update**: solution with @ptwo help, I need `$parent` and with Administration `$parent.$parent`:

```
<article class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul ng-if="isLogged()" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{'active': $parent.activeUrl === 'projects'}">
           <a href="#/projects" ng-click="$parent.activeUrl='projects'">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="isAdmin()" ng-class="{'active': $parent.$parent.activeUrl === 'admin'}">
           <a href="#/admin" ng-click="$parent.$parent.activeUrl='admin'">Administration</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
</article>
```

**Update 2** with solution without direct accessing `$parent`, but with `data` object in `applicationController` which allows me to access `activeUrl`:

```
<article class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul ng-if="isLogged()" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{'active': data.activeUrl === 'projects'}">
            <a href="#/projects" ng-click="data.activeUrl='projects'">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-if="isAdmin()" ng-class="{'active': data.activeUrl === 'admin'}">
            <a href="#/admin" ng-click="data.activeUrl='admin'">Administration</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>

applicationController= function($scope, Restangular, userService){
    $scope.data = {
        activeUrl: "admin",
        user: {
            email: undefined,
            password: undefined
        }
};
....
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067467/model-does-not-update-within-ng-if) but pay attention to the second answer (not the accepted one). By using `$parent` to access an outer variable you solve the problem now but you run the risk of seeing it come back in the future if you add a new scope for any other reason.

Comment: @Nobita You are right, I placed another working solution without `$parent` but with `data.activeUrl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use ng-if it adds a scope of its own hence on click the activeUrl is set on a child scope of the controller. Try using `$parent.activeUrl='admin'` it should work

Comment: With little changes your solution works very well - thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a function to change the activeUrl. It's never a good practice to have expressions within the view.

```
<article class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul ng-if="isLogged()" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ng-class="{'active': isActiveUrl('projects')}">
        <a href="#/projects" ng-click="updateActiveUrl('projects')">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="isAdmin()" ng-class="{'active': isActiveUrl('admin')}">
        <a href="#/admin" ng-click="updateActiveUrl('admin')">Administration</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</article>

applicationController= function($scope, Restangular, userService){
    $scope.data = {
        activeUrl: "admin",
        user: {
            email: undefined,
            password: undefined
        } };
    $scope.isActiveUrl = isActiveUrl;
    $scope.updateActiveUrl = updateActiveUrl;

    function isActiveUrl(param){
      return $scope.data.activeUrl == param;
    }

    function updateActiveUrl(param){
      $scope.data.activeUrl = param;
    }
}
```

The idea is to change member variables of the parent scope from its own scope, rather than the child scope of ng-if.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13243316)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I'll take this into consideration. I've edited the answer to provide a good answer (I hope).